# Benefiting of sched_autogroup_enabled on the desktop

Tags: linux, kernel, desktop

I am running a 2.6.37 kernel with `sched_autogroup_enabled` set to 1. I am not certain that I am seeing the benefits of this patch since:

- I am launching my applications from the desktop;
- applications launched from the desktop share the same tty;
- applications with the same tty do not benefit from the mentioned kernel feature.

How can I select some applications which should be on a different tty from the rest?

Answer (score 0):

This demo should give you an idea on the improvement:
sched_autogroup_enabled = 0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uk70SeGA7pg

sched_autogroup_enabled = 1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prxInRdaNfc

Comment: It is not a magic performance improving patch. As you see here in this comment by Lennart Poettering:
"So, this patch only has an effect of people who build kernels from an xterm with make -j all day, and at the same time want to watch a movie, from a player they also start from a terminal, but from another one."

Source: http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=128993935321081&w=2

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is probably more useful for a power user to create their own task groups. Or you could try setting custom rules for ulatencyd. I would probably disable the autogroup patch in either case so it does not conflict with the manual cgroups.

Ulatencyd FAQ: https://github.com/poelzi/ulatencyd/wiki/Faq

Cgroups Documentation: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups.txt